# The parameter 'uid' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

i am having an unknown issue with flutter app as i have updated my firebase dependencies and suddenly it marks all this.uid, keys and many more things are marked connected with firebase as an error. Maybe it could be could be caused by updating sdk, i am not sure.

**I have marked error place with ** in example**

```
 class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  Home*({this.uid, Key key})* : super(key: key);
  final String uid;

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class User {
  final String uid;
  final String name;
  final String email;
  final String city;

  User({*this.uid, this.email, this.city, this.name*});
}
```

*error: The parameter 'uid' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.*
**But its same for key as well**

```
class _ChatRoomState extends State<ChatRoom> {
  DatabaseMethods databaseMethods = new DatabaseMethods();
  *Stream chatRoomsStream;*
....
```

*error: Non-nullable instance field 'chatRoomsStream' must be initialized.*

```
final User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
```

*A value of type 'User?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'User'.*

**Its worth menioning that in every code file are marked blue**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
```

**Snippet of my used dependencies in pubspec.yaml**

```
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  firebase_auth: ^1.0.0
  firebase_core: ^1.0.2
  firebase_storage: ^8.0.0
  firebase_database: ^6.0.0
  firebase_core_platform_interface: ^4.0.0
  cloud_firestore: ^1.0.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.0
  favorite_button: ^0.0.3
  image_picker: ^0.7.3
  image_cropper: ^1.4.0
```

Comment: The code snippet for your home widget does not show errors related to firebase. But since you updated dependancies, the names used in older ersions may vary. For example, UserAuth is now User. Post those error causing widgets.

Comment: @Huthaifa Muayyad successfully added if you need i can add more, but there is too many problems in code that matches with these ones

Answer (score 4):

Change to the following:

```
 class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  Home({required this.uid, Key key})* : super(key: key);
  final String uid;

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class User {
  final String? uid;
  final String name;
  final String email;
  final String city;

  User({required this.uid, required this.email, required this.city, required this.name});
}
```

Add the `required` keyword to mark those fields as required or you can use the nullable type `?`, if the fields can be null, example:

```
class _ChatRoomState extends State<ChatRoom> {
  DatabaseMethods databaseMethods = new DatabaseMethods();
  Stream? chatRoomsStream;
```

---

Regarding this:

```
final User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
```

the method `currentUser` returns a value of type [`User?`](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/lib/src/firebase_auth.dart#L55) therefore you need to do the following:

```
final User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
```

You can read about null safety here:

https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

Comment: Thanks @peter for your solution, but think its mostly related with 'import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';' as its maked in blue for some reason and elements from it makes errors as well as app colors are marked as errors.  Also i get 'FlatButton' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. i messed up something with versions and its terrible :(

Comment: Didn't you update flutter? Since you updated check https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/release-notes/release-notes-2.0.0 and yes flatbutton is deprecated, use TextButton https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FlatButton-class.html

Comment: Yes, i havent havent updated as it worked stable and there was no issues for me @peter

Comment: execute flutter doctor in the terminal and tell me what do you get

Comment: https://www.part.lt/img/8b5194ab9c63d1b9e7569d9dd53ab666190.JPG

Comment: Yes you are using flutter 2.0 which was released at the beginning of this month, that's why you see all those errors. Check the links I provided you with

Comment: Thank you @peter for your time, i restored to previous dart version and other dependencies versions. For now i will try to finish the app with this version

Answer (score 0):

I had decided to restore the dart versions to similar to previous one, so the app could be able to work, Special thanks Peter Haddad.